# Is there any reason to not tape this vent over?

Tags: vent, central-air

I just want to make sure this wont hurt anything.

Right before I bought this house, it got a new AC and furnace but they did not replace much of the duct work. This vent is right above the AC unit and is the first vent the cold air passes. It was bleeding cold air into the basement so I covered it.

[image]

Comment: You probably want at least one vent down there, but yea, probably not there. Also note that duct tape is (ironically) not designed for ducts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether you tape it or otherwise block it, the effect will be the same and it will not cause any damage to your system; it would be no different than if there was a standard register there that was closed.

The only thing I'll note is that duct tape will eventually dry up and fall off.  Ideally you would use foil HVAC tape

[image: HVAC Tape]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/c0bbd875-88ed-48d7-b92a-993dd7d95717_4.jpg))</sub>

Unlike duct tape, this will not dry up and will hold the seal.

Comment: Thanks. I was planning on getting some foil tape (as long as I got no feed back on this damaging the system) this weekend. But at 103 outside I just grabbed the first thing I saw

Answer (score 1):

The vent was most likely put in for the winter months and could be closed for the summer time.  The thing to make sure is that you still have enough air flow.  Depending on how many other outlets you have for the volume of the blower.  If the air flow is cut back it can cause the system to run very inefficient or worse case the A coil in furnace can freeze.